# Creating a Global Backbone.js error view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to create a global error handling Backbone.js view. This view should be able to handle all server errors and react by displaying an appropriate message on the UI. Can anyone help on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I would suggest, override your Backbone.sync, and make sure all your server requests will get through a parser to error-scanning. Trigger custom events when you find errors, and have a message stack kind of view to capture these events and render these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var NotificationView = Backbone.view.extend({

initialize: function () {
    //add your error dialogue window to body.

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {

        try {
                //if you want to send error message from server side.
            if(xhr.status === 500) {
                result = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                this.show(result.message);
            }
            else if (xhr.status !== 200) { //sucess
                this.show("Something is not right !!!");
            }

            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                //success           
            }
        } catch(error) {}           
    });
},

show: function(message) {
   //show your dialogue with message.
},

hide: function() {
   //hide dialogue.
}
});
```

---

```
var notify = new NotificationView();
```